# iPhone reloading data in a table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I populate the data from my table using a loadResults routine which runs on viewDidLoad (through mHud) which works fine. However now I want to slightly alter the results from distance to accessibility (just changing the url it parses the data from)

I tried on the switch re-running my loadResults but it doesn't seem to do anything. If i change the url it parses then swap to the same page it loads the correct new results (but screws up my navigational controller and I'm pretty sure wastes a tonne of memory doing that).

So basically I have:

```
-(void)loadResults {

//routine to parse XML files 


  [self.view reloadData];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Results";

    HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    HUD.labelText = @"Loading";
    HUD.detailsLabelText = @"updating data"; 

    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadResults) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];

}
```

I've just put a button on my navigational controller which swaps between them.

So i guess in essence, how do i re load my table with the new data?

Tom

Comment: try using [outletNameOfTableView reloadData];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your controller is a subclass of UITableViewController you should modify the loadResults method:

```
-(void)loadResults {

    //routine to parse XML files 

      [self.tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

So, use **self.tableView** instead of self.view.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code is help of your

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark MBProgressHUDDelegate methods

- (void)hudWasHidden  { 
    // Remove HUD from screen when the HUD was hidded
    [HUD removeFromSuperview];
    [HUD release];
    [tbleName reloadData]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use this code.

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```